# Spring Cloud Stream Supplier function model

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to use spring cloud stream and the new functions support for configuration but I am having a problem to understand how to achieve the same result I would have with annotation configuration.

I need to send a message to the brooker, every time a user is created. With the annotation based configuration I could accomplish it like this:

```
 public UserProducer {
    
    @Autowired
    private final Source source;
    
    @Autowired
    private final UserRepository repository;

    public void saveUser(User user) {
        repository.save(user);
        source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(user).build());
    }
 }
```

Is it possible to use spring cloud stream functions to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new `StreamBridge` API for doing that. See the docs here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_streambridge

Comment: Link is outdated. The correct one is https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_streambridge