# Spring cloud stream function problem - StreamBridge call consumer multiple times

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to utilize `spring cloud stream functions` for messaging purposes between applications in `spring boot` applications. (I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62695644/spring-cloud-stream-supplier-function-model)).
I use version 3.1.0-RC1 since they introduced there a `CloudEvent` message builder  I need. I also use the `RabbitMQ` binder. I run the `RabbitMQ` locally.
I have `Application A`, that needs to deliver some data in a message (`CloudEvent` spec) to `Application B`.
So `Application B` is the receiver (Or consumer in `spring cloud stream` terms).

```java
 @Bean
   public Consumer<Message<MyMessageData>> onEventOneMessage(){
       return msg -> {
           // Get the contained message, log and return it
           MyMessageData myMessageData = msg.getPayload();
           log.debug("Received Cloud Event on event one: " + 
                   myMessageData.toString());

           // Some processing code ...
       };
   }

@Bean
   public Consumer<Message<MyMessageData>> onEventTwoMessage(){
       return msg -> {
           // Get the contained message, log and return it
           MyMessageData myMessageData = msg.getPayload();
           log.debug("Received Cloud Event to event two: " + 
                   myMessageData.toString());

           // Some processing code ...
       };
   }
```

And the `application.yaml` of `Application B` relevant configuration is:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: onEventOneMessage;onEventTwoMessage
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest
```

Then `Application A` is the **supplier\source**. Since I could not find a way to explicitly trigger the message send I used `StreamBridge` as suggested in the answer to the question I quoted.
It builds the the name of the destination with the pattern of: `on<EventName>-in-0`.

```java
private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private final StreamBridge streamBridge;

    /**
     * Sends a message to the queue
     *
     * @param message The message to send
     */
    @Override
    public void sendDirectMessage(MyMessage message) {

        if (message.getEvent() == null){
            throw new MyMessagingException("Must contain an event specification");
        }

        try {
            // Create the routing expression (function definition to look for)
            String routingExpression = String.format("on%s-in-0", message.getEvent().toString());

            // Wrap the message in CloudEvent spec message
            Message<String> inputMessage = CloudEventMessageBuilder
                    .withData(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message))
                    .setSource("https://spring.io/spring-event")
                    .setType("com.example.springevent")
                    .build();

            this.streamBridge.send(routingExpression, inputMessage);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            throw new MyMessagingException(String.format("Failed to send a message: %s", message.toString()), ex);
        }
    }
```

Since I create the destination dynamically I don't register the source at the `application.yaml` at the provider.
The `StreamBridge` works **but the consumer method is being called multiple times** (duplicated message) and not just once.
Any idea what might be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: [Habeeb Okunade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11134123) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67159534) saying "Hope this repository will help [https://github.com/HabeebCycle/spring-cloud-stream-implemention](https://github.com/HabeebCycle/spring-cloud-stream-implemention)"